# Keccak256 hash different in solidity and web3js

Tags: web3js, javascript, signature, hash

I am trying to sign a message in NodeJS and verify the signature with smart contract. Here is my code:

```
async function prepareAndSignMessage(to, amount, referenceTransaction){
    let contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(multisigABI, process.env.MULTISIG_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    //get keccak256 hash from contract
    let messageHash = await contractInstance.methods.getMessageHash(to, amount,  referenceTransaction).call();
    //sign message
    let signature = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(messageHash, process.env.ETHEREUM_PRIVATE_KEY);
    //{
    //  message: '0x9705f46c17b68492339627f99af8d148a9bf3a3075b89bb1a663bc26db530072',
    //  messageHash: '0x9ba3f82569283f1c3899ddec04c526b4f55d92d2ed6963497bbb09ee31bbd924', <-- This hash should match
    //  v: '0x1c',
    //  r: '...',
    //  s: '...',
    //  signature: '...'
    //}

}
```

And smart contract to recover & verify a signature:

```
function recover(address _to, uint256 _amount, string memory _reference) public returns(address){
    bytes32 hash = addPrefixAndHash(getMessageHash(_to, _amount, _referenece));
    //This hash should be same as one returned by web3. But it's different?????
    //....
}

function addPrefixAndHash(bytes32 _hash) public returns(bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash));
}

function getMessageHash(address _to, uint256 _amount, string memory _reference) public returns(bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_to, _amount, _reference));
}
```

Hash from `addPrefixAndHash` should match hash returned by web3js `web3.eth.accounts.sign` function. But it's not.

`web3.eth.accounts.sign` is defined here: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js#L302

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modifying web3 internal behavior doesn't look like a good idea. Web3 has [`web3.utils.soliditySha3`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3) that behaves identical to solidity's keccak256.

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and you will not bump into this problem in the first place because you will not be using JavaScrip anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by modifying web3 function and removing the part that hashed the message (at https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js#L302)

```
Accounts.prototype.sign = function sign(data, privateKey) {
if (!privateKey.startsWith('0x')) {
    privateKey = '0x' + privateKey;
}

// 64 hex characters + hex-prefix
if (privateKey.length !== 66) {
    throw new Error("Private key must be 32 bytes long");
}

//var hash = this.hashMessage(data);
var hash = data; 
var signature = Account.sign(hash, privateKey);
var vrs = Account.decodeSignature(signature);
return {
    message: data,
    messageHash: hash,
    v: vrs[0],
    r: vrs[1],
    s: vrs[2],
    signature: signature
};
};
```